# Can you display a jQuery UI modal dialog when user attempts to close the browser?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I know how to show an alert when the user exits the browser and I know how to implement a neat modal dialog using the jQuery UI library. My problem is, I'd like to implement that dialog when the user attempts to close the browser rather than display the ugly little popup box. Is this do-able?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, sorry, that's by design.  It keeps people from writing nasty things that keeps the page from being closed.

Comment: makes sense I suppose. But if you're developing an intranet app it would be nice. Thanks for the head's up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried handling the window.close() event?

Comment: can i use that in conjunction with jQuery though?